# laravel carbon get day names from a date column from a collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have this collection from a database where I have a column called "event_date".

What I want is just to get only the day names from that column that comes in a collection.

I know you can use Carbon to get the name days through, for example, a method called `->format()`, however I get an error saying that this method does not exist.

My code so far is as follows:

```
$collection = MyModel::all();
```

Inside there is the "event_date" property or column. From that, I want to get the names of the days to put them into an array or collection and finally count those days frequencies.

In order to achieve this I have tried the following:

I tried the `->pluck()` method as follows:

```
$filtered = collect([
            'myDates'=>$collection->pluck('event_date'),
        ]);
```

And the `dd($filtered)` looks like as follows:

```
Collection {#209 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "myDates" => Collection {#243 ▼
      #items: array:30 [▼
        0 => Carbon {#244 ▼
          +"date": "2017-02-05 00:00:00.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 3
          +"timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
        }
        1 => Carbon {#218 ▼
          +"date": "2017-01-15 00:00:00.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 3
          +"timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
        }
        2 => Carbon {#250 ▼
          +"date": "2016-09-25 00:00:00.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 3
          +"timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
        }
        3 => Carbon {#249 ▼
          +"date": "2016-05-22 00:00:00.000000"
          +"timezone_type": 3
          +"timezone": "America/Mexico_City"
        }
...
```

I tried to get the day names as follows:

```
$Daynames = $filtered->each(function($item,$key){
            return $item->myDates->format('l');
        });
```

But I got the following error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$myDates

Any ideas to get only the daynames into an array or collection? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're calling **format()** on the collection of dates, while you should call it on the **Carbon** objects. You need another loop that would go through all dates in **myDates** collection and format them, e.g.:

```
$Daynames = [];
$filtered->each(function($item,$key) use (&$Daynames) {
  $item->each(function($date) use (&$Daynames) {
    $Daynames[] = $date->format('l');
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice! But why do I get the `$Daynames` empty? If I echo out each `$date->format('l')` I can see the day names. But the array appears empty. I have tried `use($Daynames)` and `return $Daynames;` and it does not work either.

Answer (score 9):

You can do with with more than one way

```
Carbon::parse($date)->dayName; // Monday ... 

Carbon::parse($date)->format('l'); // Monday ...
```

custom location

```
Carbon::parse($date)->locale('fr')->dayName;// Lundi ...
```

Comment: People should see this too.

Answer (score 6):

By Carbon library we can get it easly.

1. Use Library

   ```
   use Carbon\Carbon;
   ```
2. Get date

   ```
   $date = '2018-11-15';
   $d    = new DateTime($date);
   $d->format('l');  //pass l for lion aphabet in format
   ```

Output is `Thursday`. 
It worked for me in laravel

Comment: What's the use Carbon\Carbon; command to get the same result.

Comment: Why importing Carbon?

Answer (score 6):

1. Use the library

   `use Carbon\Carbon;`
2. Parsing the date

   `$day = Carbon::parse($yourDate)->format('l')`

Answer (score 2):

nice and elegant way to achieve this using collection pipelines:

```
$days = MyModel::all()->pluck('event_date')->map(function($date) {
    return $date->format('l');
});
```